# Why HashMap instance's class type compare equal with HashMap.class?

Tags: java, generics

```
HashMap<String, Set<String>> foo = new HashMap<>();
if (foo.getClass().equals(HashMap.class)) {
    System.out.print(true);
}
```

The above code print true.
Why are these two type compare equal?
to me **foo.getClass()** contains more type info than **HashMap.class**.

Comment: What do you mean by *more type info*? Both things refer to the exact same class object. Namely the `Class<HashMap>` class. Are you referring to the generics? They are not part of the `Class` object.

Comment: @Zabuza I am from c++, Java's generics confuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java implemented generics with [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). In runtime there is no information about generics.

> Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type checks at compile time and to support generic programming. To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.
>
> Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.

Comment: *"In runtime there is no information about generics."* That's a common misconception. There isn't **much** information about generics, but there is some ([example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters())). But indeed, no new classes are created, which explains the OP's result.

Comment: Thank you very much! Java's generics seems different with C++.

Answer (score -1):

Generics aren't important during the runtime. Thus the following:

```
System.out.println(foo.getClass().equals(HashMap.class));
```

will return **true**.

Comment: That's more of an observation than an explanation to why this is the case.